# Best way to Query for single Entity based on ONE property value?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The ask: a function to retrieve a *single* `Entity` from the [Google App Engine Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/api-overview) based on a property that is *not* its `Key` or otherwise return `null` if no such object is found.

Here is the function I have currently:

```
public Entity find(DatastoreService datastore, String kind, String property, String value) {
    Filter propertyFilter =
        new FilterPredicate(property, FilterOperator.EQUAL, value);

    Query q = new Query(kind).setFilter(propertyFilter);

    List<Entity> results =
        datastore.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());

    if (results.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    return results.get(0);
}
```

Is there a one-shot API I could use instead or are there any optimization suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `PreparedQuery#asSingleEntity()`:

```
public Entity find(DatastoreService datastore,
        String kind, String property, String value)
        throws TooManyResultsException {
    Filter propertyFilter =
        new FilterPredicate(property, FilterOperator.EQUAL, value);

    Query q = new Query(kind).setFilter(propertyFilter);

    return datastore.prepare(q).asSingleEntity();
}
```

The only real difference between this and your code is that the underlying query sets a `LIMIT` of 2.